# How to use a temporary variable in Python 2.7 - memory

Tags: python, variables, memory

I  save 'haystack' in a temporary variable, but when I modify 'haystack', the temporary variable change too. Why? Help please? it's normal? in PHP I didn't have this problem.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

haystack = [1,'Two',3]   
tempList = haystack   
print 'TempList='    
print tempList   
iterable = 'hello'  
haystack.extend(iterable)   
print 'TempList='   
print tempList
```

Return in Console

```
TempList=
[1, 'Two', 3]
TempList=
[1, 'Two', 3, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

But I haven't modified the variable 'tempList'.
Help, please.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not creating a copy of the list; you merely create a second reference to it.

If you wanted to create a temporary (shallow) copy, do so explicitly:

```
tempList = list(haystack)
```

or use the full-list slice:

```
tempList = haystack[:]
```

You modify the mutable list in-place when calling `.extend()` on the object, so all references to that list will see the changes.

The alternative is to create a new list by using concatenation instead of extending:

```
haystack = [1,'Two',3]   
tempList = haystack  # points to same list
haystack = haystack + list(iterable)  # creates a *new* list object
```

Now the `haystack` variable has been re-bound to a new list; `tempList` still refers to the old list.

Comment: Good explanation. The alternative is to just not use mutating methods—instead of `haystack.extend(iterable)` do `haystack = haystack + list(iterable)` (or `haystack = itertools.chain(haystack, iterable)` if you don't need a list).

Answer (score 3):

`tempList` and `haystack` are just two names that you bind to the same `list`.
Make a copy:

```
tempList = list(haystack) # shallow copy
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of the difference of behaviour between lists and standalone variables in Python. This is because `tempList = haystack` doesn't *copy* haystack values to `tempList`, but assigns address of `haystack` to address of `tempList`. That is, now you are referring to the same place in memory by two names. So modifying one will modify another. To copy values you can do `tempList = list(haystack)`.